# Named pipes without child process

Tags: c, named-pipes, fifo

I used a FIFO for a simple read/write programme where the input from user is written to standard output by the writer function. The question is however, am I able to run this program without creating a child process (with the `fork()` operation). From what I see from examples about FIFOs, most read/write programmes with a named pipe/FIFO are done with 2 files - one for reading and one for writing. Could I do these all in a file?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* read from user  */
void reader(char *namedpipe) {
  char c;
  int fd;
  while (1) {
    /* Read from keyboard  */
    c = getchar();     
    fd = open(namedpipe, O_WRONLY); 
    write(fd, &c, 1);
    fflush(stdout); 
  }
}

/* writes to screen */
void writer(char *namedpipe) {
  char c;
  int fd;
  while (1) {
    fd = open(namedpipe, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, &c, 1);
    putchar(c);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int child,res;            

  if (access("my_fifo", F_OK) == -1) {
    res = mkfifo("my_fifo", 0777);
    if (res < 0) {
    return errno;
    }
  }

    child = fork();       
    if (child == -1)      
      return errno;
    if (child == 0) {     
      reader("my_fifo");   
    }
    else {                
      writer("my_fifo");  
    }


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put a lock on the file, or else you could attempt to be reading when someone else is writing.  You'll also want to flush the write buffer, or your changes to the fifo might actually not be recorded until the kernel write buffer fills and then writes to the file (in linux, write doesn't guarantee a write happens at that exact moment.  i see you're flushing stdout, but you should also fsync on the file descriptor. This will cause the file to lock during any write operation so that no one else can write.  In order to lock the file for reading, you might have to use a semaphore.